# Grunt this.files for non-multitasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

When defining a multitask in Gruntjs, I am able to do

```
grunt.registerMultiTask("taskName", "taskDescription", function () {
  this.files.forEach(function (mapping) {
    // mapping.src and mapping.dest are defined here,
    // no matter which format was used to configure files in the task
  });
});
```

Why is `this.files` not available when doing `grunt.registerTask`? Or is it the case that I simply am not allowed to use the different file formats in the task config when it is not a multitask (compact format, object format, array format, defined [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks))?

What's the easiest way to get access to the src and destination file mappings when not inside a multitask? I want to do

```
grunt.initConfig({
  my_task: {
    // I don't want to define a target here
    files: {
      // I want to be able to use any format here
      "my/target/folder": "my/src/files/*"
    }
}

grunt.registerTask("my_task", "description", function () {
  this.files // ==> undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Grunts API, you have to run the task with arguments for you to be able to get any arguments in the `taskFunction` callback.

If you run `grunt foo`, your will get `foo, no args` and if you run `grunt foo:testing:123` will result in `foo, testing 123`.

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'A sample task that logs stuff.', function(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", no args");
  } else {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", " + arg1 + " " + arg2);
  }
});
```

The `this` object in the context of grunt.registerTask functions `taskFunction` callback will give you this ..

```
{ nameArgs: 'foo',
  name: 'foo',
  args: [],
  flags: {},
  async: [Function],
  errorCount: [Getter],
  requires: [Function],
  requiresConfig: [Function],
  options: [Function] }
```

while this is the context of grunt.registerMultiTask functions `taskFunction` callback will give you this ..

```
{ nameArgs: 'my_task:files',
  name: 'my_task',
  args: [],
  flags: {},
  async: [Function],
  errorCount: [Getter],
  requires: [Function],
  requiresConfig: [Function],
  options: [Function],
  data: { thefile: 'thesource' },
  files: [],
  filesSrc: [Getter],
  target: 'files' }
```

To answer your question the `files` object in your `my_task` task isn't accessible in the context you need it in.